# chown user:group except nobody

Tags: linux, shell, command, cpanel

I am trying to figure out how to recursively change user and group on an entire directory while leaving the nobody user intact

```
chown -vR user:group /home/mydir
```

- will change the ownership of every file under /mydir when I would like to leave all files that belong to nobody:nobody unchanged

(this makes sense when you are trying to move a subdomain to a new domain on a cPanel server and don't have the option to use the Modify an Account feature since there are several other subdomains that need to belong to the own user:group) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think chown(1) alone will do, but with find you can do what you want.

```
find /your/directory \! -user nobody -exec echo chown user:group {} \;
```

Replace `/your/directory` and `user:group` with values of your choice. Then run this and when you're sure it does what you want, Remove `echo` from `-exec` and things get actually done.

A good practice to first echo on terminal what would be done and then proceed either with corrections or removing the echo, in case output seems to be what actually should be done.